# Prompting Database Login When generating report from a listview contents to crystal reports

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I got  this  code and getting an error prompt. Database Login. Even I put the right password, it always says Login Failed.

```
Dim report As New ReportDocument
report.Load("rptPrntIss.rpt")

report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tbl_issued.TransactionID}=" & txtIssID.Text & "AND ({tbl_transaction.Department}=" & cBoxDpt.Text & ")"
frmPrnt.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
frmPrnt.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
frmPrnt.ShowDialog()
```

Maybe this code is not right, because everything was perfect without this code.

Answer (score 0):

use [setdatabaselogon()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691462%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function to prevent prompting database logon each time.

it will be like

```
report.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", "server", "dbname", false)
```

in some cases this will also wont work(had some situations recently for me),in that case we need to specify database login for each tables in report.

like

```
dim connInfo as new ConnectionInfo()
connInfo.ServerName = yourserver
connInfo.DatabaseName = "dbname"
connInfo.UserID = "username"
connInfo.Password = "password"
dim  tableLogOnInfo as new TableLogOnInfo()
tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connInfo

   foreach Table as table in reportDoc.Database.Tables

      table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo)
      table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = connInfo.ServerName
      table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = connInfo.DatabaseName
      table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = connInfo.UserID
      table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = connInfo.Password
   next
```

hope this helps.

Comment: what should  i replace  on reportDoc.Database.Tables?

Comment: yourreportname.database.tables

Comment: setting each tables sir. . Sir. by the way . I  only want to print my  listview  multiple items and pass it to crystal reports. sir can u help me to this?

Comment: then try with this links,in the code you posted has no connection with printing from listview. [Generate Crystal Report from List View](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?433644-Generate-Crystal-Report-from-List-View-%28or-other-source%29&p=2658331#post2658331)

Comment: But i refer to this  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boEmNGmKrlE) it shows that he used that code to be able to print  what user selects.

Comment: so you are printing from database itself.then you must be providing wrong username and password.else it should work.

Comment: Yes sir.  my username is  root and password  is password123... but then . it always prompt.

Comment: try setting the first solution setdatabaselogon()...with correct credentials.

Comment: try this one also. this is my code. report.SetDatabaseLogon("root", "password123", "localhost", "database", False) but still it prompts...   Hmm. maybe where i will put it?

Comment: put it right after report.load method.also is your databasename 'database'??

Comment: Yes sir . Still the same . :(

Comment: Sir, any idea to  print my  listview content  to crystal reports? :(  i tried so many times. but it didn't  help me . :(  Please help.

Comment: cant think of a solution now :(..above links must work for sure..cant figure out where you are doing wrong....sorry :(

Comment: Its Ok sir. Thank You for your time .  GODBLESS. I'd appreciate it much.